# Why Phpmyadmin don't understand MD5?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, md5

I have phpmyadmin version 4.0.10.20 in debian Squeeze. it's LAMP server.

If I run SQL Query: in PHPMYADMIN

```
SELECT MD5('testing');

The result is :
MD5('testing')  
6165326231666361353135393439653564353466623232623865643935353735
```

In Mysql consol directly: (in the same Server)

```
mysql> SELECT MD5('testing');
    +----------------------------------+
    | MD5('testing')                   |
    +----------------------------------+
    | ae2b1fca515949e5d54fb22b8ed95575 |
    +----------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What do you think about it ?
--> I have never seen that !

Comment: MD5 is old you should not be using this hash function annymore.

Comment: `616532...`  is the hex ascii code for `ae2..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just different representation of the same.

```
A=61
E=65
2=32
B=62
...
5=35

61 65 32 62 31 66 63 61 35 31 35 39 34 39 65 35 64 35 34 66 62 32 32 62 38 65 64 39 35 35 37 35
 a  e  2  b  1  f  c  a  5  1  5  9  4  9  e  5  d  5  4  f  b  2  2  b  8  e  d  9  5  5  7  5
```

Comment: I have no idea. Probably author of PHPMyAdmin was affraid that MD5 would output data in binary form, or maybe it did in the past? Running SELECT UNHEX(MD5('testing')); in PHPMyAdmin should give you same result. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: I can't test this because my system is too new, but I think unchecking the "Show binary contents as HEX" checkbox under the "Options" area will give the results you expect. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xqhS.png